# How to update List View through Array List using Async Task in Android?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask

I am following the Earthquake app from udacity.com . I am stuck in updating the view after the json parsing using async task .After getting the arraylist object in onPostExecute method for doInBackground method i don't understand how to update the view, my app screen comes blank every time, i have a custom word adaptor class with some text view and a list view This is the code of EarthquakeActivity.java class

```
 package com.example.android.quakereport;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

            private static final String USGS_REQUEST_URL =
                    "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-05-02&minfelt=50&minmagnitude=5";


ArrayList<Earthquak_Data> list=new ArrayList<>();
EarthquakAdaptor earthquakAdaptor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

    EarthquakAsyncTask task= new EarthquakAsyncTask();
    task.execute(USGS_REQUEST_URL);



}

private class EarthquakAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<Earthquake_Data>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Earthquak_Data> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ArrayList<Earthquak_Data> result=QueryUtils.Fentch_EarthQuake_Data(USGS_REQUEST_URL);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Earthquak_Data> earthquake_datas) {
        super.onPostExecute(earthquak_datas);



    }
}
}
```

After getting this earthquake_data how i can update the view from onPostExecute method . Please tell me the code . I am stuck here from weeks. Before this i used offline json data that time all worked fine.

Comment: you need to pass the list you receives in onPost method to the adapter and then set the adapter to the listview or recyclerview whichever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arrayadapter to populate the listview like below...

```
 // Construct the data source as in background
    ArrayList<Earthquak_Data> result = .......
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views in postexecute
    UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, result);
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

More details [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView).

Comment: UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, result);  this gives me a error that Earthquake Adapter cannot be applied to EarthquakeActivity.AsyncTask

Comment: @adityapratap: Try UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(EarthquakeActivity.this, result); See what happens.

Comment: Also you need to modify UsersAdapter (any name) to accept Earthquak_Data objects.